# passing javascript object from one channel to other channel in mirth

Tags: javascript, channel, mirth

In **Channel A** i am getting XML as input.Incoming XML mentioned below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bookstore>
<books>
<book>
<title>SpringInAction</title>
<NoOfCopies>10</NoOfCopies>
</book>
<book>
<title>HibernateInAction</title>
<NoOfCopies>8</NoOfCopies>
</book>
<book>
<title>JSFInAction</title>
<NoOfCopies>5</NoOfCopies>
</book>
<book>
<title>StrutsInAction</title>
<NoOfCopies>9</NoOfCopies>
</book>
<book>
<title>JSPInAction</title>
<NoOfCopies>4</NoOfCopies>
</book>
</books>
</bookstore>
```

I am parsing this XML in Edit Transformer of the Source  and making JavaScript object and putting this JavaScript object into a channel Map like this:

```
var book=new Object();
book.title = msg['books']['book'][0]['title'].toString();
book.copies = msg['books']['book'][0]['NoOfCopies'].toString();
logger.info("book "+book);
channelMap.put("book",book);
```

Now i want to pass this JavaScript object to other **Channel B** from destination of **Channel A** and **Channel B** receives this JavaScript object as input and does the rest of the processing .Is it possible in Mirth?

I am using Mirth Version 2.2.1.5861.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before saving the channel variable, serialize it (json object).

In your channel destination, write out the "book" variable.

So something like this:

In Transformer

```
var book=new Object();
book.title = msg['books']['book'][0]['title'].toString();
book.copies = msg['books']['book'][0]['NoOfCopies'].toString();
logger.info("book "+book);

var Jbook = JSON.stringify(book);
channelMap.put("Jbook",Jbook );
```

In Destination Template

```
${jbook}
```

Then on the receiving channel

```
var book = JSON.parse(msg.toString());
```

I have not verified this code, but it should give you a coding strategy.

See [Mirth Discussion about JSON](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=6170)

Also:  Please see our HealthcareIT project proposal at [area51.StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51758/healthcare-it).  This would be a good question to ask.

Comment: I just uncovered this, ChronoFish is right, the JSON object should be serialized, or you can use that as the message template itself.  If you do routeMessage, I couldn't get the JSON object to pass between channels, but if I serialized it (convert to string), it passes just fine).  Performance was great, was able to process 100 MB file in 10 minutes (each record is 5k or so). (Note I had to do my own parsing using the message grouping javascript functionality to get this speed).

Answer (score 1):

Objects can be passed using the Global Channel Map. Other two maps are persisted to the database and therefore the Mirth Connect engine serializes them to strings. However, for the Global Channel Map you should handle the context in your script (as the name suggests, it exists not only in a message or channel context).

There is a sample of passing the object using the Global Channel Map [here](http://mirthconnect.shamilpublishing.com).

Comment: be careful using the global map.  It's not a per-instance variable...it is literally a global variable.  A change in one channel changes the value in the other.  If you are processing multiple messages the value that you are expecting in channel B may have already changed in Channel A.  Global vars are great for configuration type settings.  *maybe* as a type of Mutext - but I would avoid using globals for passing variables in the manner you outlined.  You're better off serializing as I showed in my answer